# Display UIStepper's value instead of minimumValue in UILabel at app's launch

Tags: swift, uikit, uilabel, iboutlet, uistepper

I have a `UIStepper` with the following parameters:

- `value: 40`
- `minimumValue: 35`
- `maximumValue: 45`

I want to update the `UILabel` (linked to it) at app' launch in order to make the it displays `value`. It's currently displaying the `minimumValue` by default and I don't know why. Any ideas ?

- In my file I declared my `IBOutlets` first (`UIStepper` & `UILabel`) related to the size value
- I declared the `showSizeLabel()` function and called it when the app is launch in `viewDidLoad()`
- I then called it everytime the `UIStepper` was updated.

Here is the code for my `ViewController.swift` file :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var sizeLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sizeStepper: UIStepper!
    
    var size: String = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
//        Sets the first UI's display
        showSizeValue()
        
    }
    
//    Updates in real time the shoe size displayed on screen
    func showSizeValue() {
        sizeLbl.text = String(Int(sizeStepper.value))
        size = sizeLbl.text ?? ""
        updateShoeImage()
    }
    
//    Stepper pressed
    @IBAction func sizeChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        showSizeValue()
        updateShoeImage() // Update the shoe image if size is pressed
        updateOrderResult() // Update order result's message when size is pressed
    }
}
```

Comment: When I run my app and use a breakpoint on this line : sizeLbl.text = String(Int(sizeStepper.value)), sizeStepper.value is equal to the minimumValue of my UIStepper. Do you know why ? Why doesn’t it display the « value » property instead of the « minimumValue » ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an iOS bug. The `value` property of the stepper set in the storyboard is not honored unless the minimum value is set to 0.

For example, if you setup the stepper in the storyboard with a min value of 0, a max value of 100, a value of 50, and a step of 1, then when the view controller loads, the stepper will show a value of 50 as expected.

But if you change the min value to 1 and leave everything else the same, then the value will show as 1 instead of 50 when the view controller loads.

The simple work around is to set the initial value in code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sizeStepper.value = 40 // work around iOS bug
    
    // Sets the first UI's display
    showSizeValue()  
}
```